# How to overwrite "setter" in peewee field?

Tags: python, enums, setter, peewee

Given the following code, I would like to modify `EnumField` in a way that I can pass strings into the `MyClass` constructor and they are autocasted to enum right away. I thought of overwriting the "setter", but couldn't find it in peewee's code.

```
from enum import Enum
from peewee import CharField, Model


class EnumField(CharField):
    "Custom field to support enums"

    def __init__(self, enum, **kwargs):
        super(EnumField, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.enum = enum

    def db_value(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, Enum):
            return str(value.name)  # convert enum to str
        elif isinstance(value, basestring):
            return value
        return None

    def python_value(self, value):
        if value:
            return self.enum[value]  # convert str to enum
        return None

    def clone_base(self, **kwargs):
        return super(EnumField, self).clone_base(enum=self.enum, **kwargs)


class FooEnum(Enum):
    FOO = "foo"
    BAR = "bar"


class MyClass(Model):
    field1 = EnumField(FooEnum)


my_class = MyClass(field1='foo')
type(my_class.field1) == FooEnum  # False, it's str but I would like it to be autocasted

my_class.save()
my_class = MyClass.get()
type(my_class.field1) == FooEnum  # True
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Peewee docs for fields](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#fields) it looks like the method you are missing is `coerce`:

> coerce(value)
>
> This method is a shorthand that is used, by default, by both db_value and python_value. You can usually get away with just implementing this.
>
> ```
> Parameters:  value – arbitrary data from app or backend
> Return type: python data type
> ```

I would make `coerce` be the same as `python_value`:

```
def python_value(self, value):
    if value:
        return self.enum[value]  # convert str to enum
    return None
coerce = python_value
```

Comment: Looks promising, but coerce/python_value is not called for me on object initiali(s|z)ation. :-(